# I want to read the PDF file content by content

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file, pdf

I want to read a PDF file having lots of text, images, tables in it. I want to read the entire file content by content page by page, from top to bottom.

For example:

- The top of the page contains the Heading
- Then on left hand side the contents and on the right hand side images

So I first want to get the heading then the contents then the images.

Is there any open source for reading the PDF or any coding reference for **.net 2.0 or greater version**?

### Edit

Hi Konamiman, I make use of iTextSharp but unable to read the document. For clarification, this is the code I am using in case of iTextSharp

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader documentReader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\pdfClownPDFReader\pdfClownPDFReader\Hongkong Buffet.pdf");
            //MessageBox.Show(documentReader.NumberOfPages.ToString());
            PdfStamper PDFS = new PdfStamper(documentReader, m);
            PdfDictionary dictonary = documentReader.GetPageN(1);
            PdfObject obj = dictonary.Get(PdfName.TEXT);
```

I also tried PDFSharp.

Comment: From the close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 1):

There is for example [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Hi Konamiman,
I make use of iTextSharp but unable to read the document.
For more clarification this is the code I am using in case of iTextSharp
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader documentReader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\pdfClownPDFReader\pdfClownPDFReader\Hongkong Buffet.pdf");
   //MessageBox.Show(documentReader.NumberOfPages.ToString());
   PdfStamper PDFS = new PdfStamper(documentReader, m);
   PdfDictionary dictonary = documentReader.GetPageN(1);
   PdfObject obj = dictonary.Get(PdfName.TEXT);

I also tried PDFSharp
Please help